# How to fully develop Django projects in the cloud?

Tags: python, django, cloud

I have been working with Django on Linux with Sublime Text for a while, but I constantly switch to Windows for graphics design and gaming. I wonder what's the most effective way to develop Django completely in the cloud without having to setup new Django environment for every OS I touch. It would be fantastic if I can just sync the project files from DigitalOcean and edit them on Sublime Text, since online IDEs/terminal from PythonAnywhere, Cloud9, etc. are quite slow and unresponsive.

Comment: I'm on windows as well, but I use a Linux virtual machine for all my development, so I don't have to switch. I've tried a dual boot and developing in windows as well, but I'd highly recommend a VM.

Answer (score 0):

Developing directly in production environment is highly discouraged. You should develop locally using version control systems (git) and test suites to check everything works before the deploy.

Once you've checked everything works, you can pull changes from the remote repository to apply the modifications or use something like jenkins for continuous integration.

But, if you still want to modify your code directly in the cloud. Pycharm is a nice IDE that allows you to work with remove projects. I don't know if this is possible with Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

Do you not use [git](https://git-scm.com/) ?
You'd just have to push and pull code changes from all your different machines after you've cloned your entire project repository for the first time.

As far as setup of your environment goes, learn to use build scripts or frameworks, like Vagrant/Chef etc.
Use a CI too, to find out if your builds fail.